# Is there an option to set Cache-Control on Cloudflare for specific files?

Tags: caching, cloudflare, cdn, browser-cache

When I visit my ReactJS website on my browser, it loads a cached version, and will not fetch a new version unless I Ctrl+Shift+F5 to force reload.

I have looked into the Cloudflare settings and recommendations and it seems that I have to set Cache-Control: max-age=31536000 for build/static assets, and Cache-Control: no-cache for everything else.

I have tried setting Browser-Cache-TTL option to 2 minutes, which made my browser fetch the latest version of my website when my last visit was more than 2 minutes ago.

However, I don't want the browser to fetch all the build/static assets as well, as they will have a different file name each time, and not caching it will only make unnecessary requests to my web server.

Thank you for reading my question.